# How to prevent two user get same unique key?

Tags: php, algorithm, codeigniter

I am creating a system to generate unique keys. It works for now. But, I haven't tested it with many users. Users may click a button and then get his unique number, as simple as that.

But, How to prevent multiple users getting the same unique keys,if they press the button exactly in the same time (even in ms scale)? The button is on client side, so I must do something in the back end.

This is the unique key looks like:
`19/XXXXXX-ABC/XYZ`

The `XXXXXX` is auto increment number from `000001` to `999999`. I have this code but didn't know if it's reliable enough to handle my issue.

```
    $autoinc = $this->MPenomoran->get_surat($f_nomor)->jumlah_no+1; //count data in table and added 1

    $no_1   = date('y')+2;
    $no_2   = str_pad($autoinc, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $no_3   = "-ABC/XYZ";

    $nomor      = $no_1."/".$no_2.$no_3; 

    $returned_nomor     = $nomor;           

    $success =  array ('nomor' => $returned_nomor); //sent unique keys to user's view
```

Comment: Can you just add an auto increment column in the database? That way you can let the database ensure that ID remains unique.

Comment: what will happen to the 1000000th user?

Comment: @vhu nope. In the table. there's a `type` column. and the increment should be different each `type`

Comment: @PetarPetrovic user cannot get the keys because it's reaching the limit. the limit may change though.

Comment: Switch to UUID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Can be done easily in PHP via ramsey/uuid (https://github.com/ramsey/uuid)

Comment: How about let there be auto increment column that is row. Then you just use that as basis for the "your_id". e.g. in MySQL `SELECT id,concat('19',id,'-ABC/XYZ') as your_id from yourtable`. You could even materialize `your_id` using triggers or separate update statement within the transaction.

Comment: You have a line of gobbledygook code that we are supposed to intuit magically as to what it does?   `$autoinc = $this->MPenomoran->get_surat($f_nomor)->jumlah_no+1;`?  Unless there is serialization or locking you will likely get duplicates if there are 2 simultaneous requests.

Comment: @vhu so, the auto increment column's value is a duplicate each rows?

Comment: @NilsRückmann I can't change the key format to UUID

Comment: I guess this is for learning purpose, right? Otherwise I would suggest you use existing implementation. For your question, if you have to generate the token in client side, then you must check in server side

Comment: @gview well, it's a piece of script. but, I think it's basically describe what't going on in the script

Comment: @PetarPetrovic any suggestion for the checking in server side?

Comment: for example check if there exists a user with the same key in the db?

Comment: yes, I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: It doesn't describe anything.  You have a piece of a class, with a line of code that references an object calling a method with a parameter, that returns an object and dereferences an internal variable.  And no code for any of them.

Comment: append `time()` or `user_id` with your unique key

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't want to come out and tell us what the platform is for this, or what the limitations to that platform are.

The first thing that jumps out is that your format is limited by year, to 999999 total unique keys.  Very odd, but presumably you understand that limit, and would need to put in some code to deal with hitting the maximum number.

**Approaches**

***REDIS based***

This would be very simple with a REDIS server using the [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr).  Since INCR is atomic, you essentially have a solution just by creating a key named for your year + 2, should it not exist, and using INCR on it from there on out.

You would need to utilize some [php redis client](https://redis.io/clients#php), and there are a variety of them with strengths and weaknesses to each that I'm not going to go into.

Redis is also great for caching, so if at all possible that is the first thing I would look into.

**MySQL Based**

There are a few different solutions using mysql.  They are involved, so I'll just outline them because I don't want to spend time writing a novel.

***Note:***  Y*ou will need to translate these into the appropriate PHP code (mysqli or PDO) where as noted, parameters are passed, transactions started etc.*

***MySQL - create your own sequence generator***

1. Create a table named "Sequence" with this basic structure:

   `name varchar(2) PK
   nextval unsigned int default 1`
   engine=InnoDB

The underlying query would be something like this:

```
BEGIN_TRANS;
SELECT nextval FROM Sequence WHERE name = '$no_1' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE Sequence SET nextval = nextval + 1;
END_TRANS;
```

This code emulates a serialized Oracle style sequence.  It is safe from a concurrency standpoint, because MySQL will lock the row briefly, then increment it upon completion.

***MySQL - Autoincrement on multi-value PK***

This comes with some caveats.

It is generally incompatible with replication.
The underlying table must be myisam

```
name varchar(2) PK
lastval unsigned int AUTO_INCREMENT PK
engine=MyISAM
```

Your underlying query would be:

```
INSERT INTO Sequence (name) VALUES ('$no_1')
```

This depends on mysql supporting a multi-column key where the 2nd column is an AUTO_INCREMENT.  It's behavior is such that it acts like a sequence for each unique name.

You would then use the relevant api's built-in approach to getting the mysql LAST_INSERT_ID().  For example with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

***Other alternatives***

You could also use semaphores, files with locking, and all sorts of other ideas to create a sequence generator that would work well in a monolithic (one server for everything) environment.  MySQL and Redis would serve a cluster, so those are more robust options from that standpoint.

The important thing is that whatever you do, you test it out using a load tester like [siege](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege) or [Boom](https://github.com/tarekziade/boom) to generate multiple requests at your web level.